# Applying width to table cell when colspan is applied

Tags: html, css

Even though i have applied table-layout fixed, table td cell are not taking width,
is it possible to apply width for td cell without changing table display property.

HTML:

```css
    table {
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #dadada;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid #dadada;
    }
    
    .td-1 {
      width: 480px;
    }
    .td-2 {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .td-3 {
      width: 290px;
    }
    .td-4 {
      width: 100px;
    }
    .td-5 {
      width: 390px;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="td-1">This is Amazing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="td-2">This is beautiful</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="td-3">This is kinda of nothing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-4">This is Awesome</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="td-5">This is Sick</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried to give the `td` elements styling inline? For example - `<td class="td-4" style="value">This is Awesome</td>`

Comment: @JordanMiguel i have applied but no use [https://codepen.io/yashutoro/pen/gzOXqx](https://codepen.io/yashutoro/pen/gzOXqx)

Answer (score 0):

Tables take their column widths from the first row. With this in mind I would approach this by creating an initial empty ghost row which does not have any colspan. This allows you to specify the exact width of each column. The row can be 1px high so it is barely visible.

Comment: I have tried you approach in codepen but it's not working.
[https://codepen.io/yashutoro/pen/ELxbeq](https://codepen.io/yashutoro/pen/ELxbeq)

Comment: If you are trying to make columns different widths in different rows then that is simply not possible. That is not how tables work.